# Unexpected HttpURLConnection connection behavior

Tags: java, sockets, https, applet, network-protocols

I am converting an Applet into a Desktop Application, and one of the internal program's services includes a SOAP client, designed to send information to a remote server. Here is a piece of the code in charge of this process:

```
package my.package.app.utils;

import my.package.app.main.MainClass;
import my.package.app.org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SoapClient {

    public static JSONObject callMethod(String path, String method, Object... args) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String            data       = null;
        try {
            data = parseXML(method, args);

            MainClass.debug("Making http POST connections to : " + path);

            URL           u  = new URL(path);
            URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", method);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            OutputStream out  = connection.getOutputStream();
            Writer       wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

            wout.write(data);
            wout.flush();
            wout.close();

            InputStream            in  = connection.getInputStream();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder        db  = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document               doc = db.parse(in);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList childs       = doc.getElementsByTagName("return");
            String   responseText = childs.item(0).getTextContent();

            if ("false".equals(responseText)) {
                return null;
            }

            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseText);

            in.close();
            return response;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String parseXML(String method, Object... args) {

        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();

        xml.append(XMLTemplates.soapHeader);
        xml.append("<ns1:");
        xml.append(method);
        xml.append(">");

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            String dataType = "xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"";

            xml.append("<param");
            xml.append(i);
            xml.append(" ");

            if (args[i] instanceof Integer) {
                dataType = "xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\"";
            }

            if (args[i] instanceof Double) {
                dataType = "xsi:type=\"xsd:decimal\"";
            }

            if (args[i] instanceof Boolean) {
                dataType = "xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\"";
            }

            xml.append(dataType);
            xml.append(">");
            xml.append(String.valueOf(args[i]));
            xml.append("</param");
            xml.append(i);
            xml.append(">");
        }

        xml.append("</ns1:");
        xml.append(method);
        xml.append(">");

        xml.append(XMLTemplates.soapFooter);

        return xml.toString();
    }

}
```

When the **callMethod**  is used, it received in my case a **path** string with an URL with HTTPS protocol like this: "https://fileserver.myserver.net:9000/lf_soap_document_server_main.php".

When running the **callMethod** with that URL, the **applet's Java console** displays the following:

```
18:15:45.476-DEBUG: Making http POST connections to : https://fileserver.myserver.net:9000/lf_soap_document_server_main.php
network: Connecting https://fileserver.myserver.net:9000/lf_soap_document_server_main.php with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://fileserver.myserver.net:9000/ with proxy=DIRECT
```

and the process completes successfully.

But when the same piece of code, with the same information is executed from the Desktop Application version, the following happens:

```
18:28:29.991-DEBUG: Making http POST connections to : https://fileserver.myserver.net:9000/lf_soap_document_server_main.php
network: Connecting https://fileserver.myserver.net:9000/lf_soap_document_server_main.php with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://fileserver.myserver.net:9000 with proxy=DIRECT
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Here the problems occurs when **OutputStream out  = connection.getOutputStream();** is called. And please note that the log message changes the protocol of the URL from https:// to socket://, and also seems to remove the last slash (/).

This is the full exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
  at my.package.app.utils.SoapClient.callMethod(SoapClient.java:42)
  at my.package.app.services.scanner.LFScanner$SoapUpload.run(LFScanner.java:746)
```

The desktop application uses Jetty to create a connection to a secure websocket server, and also creates a local websocket server in the user's machine, but none of them has business with the SoapClient class where the problem happens.

I have tested setting a 5 minutes timeout for connection and read to the HttpURLConnection instance but the problem keeps happening on the desktop application in less than a minute.

I am using 1.8.0_111-b14 as runtime to execute the programs (applet and desktop application), on a Windows 10 machine, 64 bits.

I need to know if there is anything wrong with this code, or if there is a missing setting here to prevent this from happening.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a proxy to access the internet from the desktop? If so, your Java code also needs to use it.

Comment: No, I am not using a proxy.

Comment: Or a firewall? Can you open the URL in a web browser?

Comment: Yes. I can open the URL on a browser without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the problematic piece of code in an isolated program, only with the minimum needed code to reproduce, and found that the problem was actually on the server side, the one that provides the URL with the SOAP services. Most of the tests so far worked fine with other programs, but found the SOAP url having availability problems in other programs as well, not just Java, which explains the problem in general.

**The code used to connect and consume the SOAP services is OK, the problem is on the destination URL.**

I still don't know the reason why the Java console displays different protocols in the debug information when trying to access the SOAP URL, but it does not seem to be a problem anyways (for now).